# What programming language will enable me to enter a very long number without converting it to floating point?

Tags: math, programming-languages, digits

What would be the best way to do the following.

Enter a very long number, lets say 500,000 digits long without it going into scientific notation; and then am able to do math with it, like +2 etc.?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: It is a 500,000 digit, positive integer.

Comment: What do you have against scientific notation?

Comment: Pretty much any language would. You may have to write some code, though :-)

Comment: Python does it without any kind of special library at all.

Also, the bc program for Unix, which is a full programming language, can also do it without any kind of special library.

Comment: Surely he means floating point.

Comment: Any language will. If not out of the box, you can always write your own handler.

Comment: @unknown: Any turing-complete programming language that accepts textual input and has access to enough memory, anyway.

Comment: @Gurdas because scientific notation is not a number. It's a notation format that cannot express a number such as 10^500000 + 2 without **rounding error**.

Comment: @snicker: yes it can, it just needs a *lot* of digits. Double-precision floating point numbers (which are just one implementation based on scientific notation) don't have enough digits, by a long way, but there's no inherent limit to scientific notation in general.

Answer (score 13):

[Python](http://www.python.org/) and [Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) have native support, libraries exist for [C++](https://gmplib.org/), [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library), [.NET](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/),  ...

Comment: I wouldn't describe Java's BigInteger class as "Native Support".

Comment: I dunno, BigInteger isn't as "native" or as pleasant to use as what Python provides, but at least it comes with the language.

Answer (score 11):

I know that Erlang has support for unlimited size int arithmetics.

Comment: +1 Erlang is very popular for this. And it is free... unlike Mathematica.

Comment: Erlang does not have arbitrary precision floats.

Comment: Further clarification: having browsed the source code of Erlang, the integer arithmetic is written in C so it very much native IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Python does this out of the box with no special library.  So does 'bc' (which is a full programming language masquerading as a calculator) for Unix systems.

Answer (score 6):

Python is pretty good on its own, but better with [`gmpy`](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) (which bridges it to the GMP library others have mentioned, or alternately to the MPIR kinda-work-alike one [[work in progress;-)]]).  Consider:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'x=int("1"*9999); y=int("2"*9999)' 'x*y'
100 loops, best of 3: 6.46 msec per loop
```

i.e., in pure Python, multiply two 10K-digits ints takes 6.5 milliseconds or so.  And...:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'from gmpy import mpz; x=mpz("1"*9999); y=mpz("2"*9999)' 'x*y'
1000 loops, best of 3: 326 usec per loop
```

...with gmpy at hand, the operation will be about 20 times faster.  If you have hundreds rather than thousands of digits, it's even more extreme:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'x=int("1"*199999); y=int("2"*199999)' 'x*y'
10 loops, best of 3: 675 msec per loop
```

vs

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'from gmpy import mpz; x=mpz("1"*199999); y=mpz("2"*199999)' 'x*y'
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 msec per loop
```

so, with 200k digits instead of just 10k, gmpy's speed advantage is 38 times or so.

If you routinely need to handle integers of this magnitude, Python + gmpy is really a workable solution (of course I'm biased, since I did author and care for gmpy over the last few years exactly because I ♥ Python (hey, my *license plate* is P♥thon!-) *and* in one of my hobby (combinatorial arithmetic) I **do** have to deal with such numbers pretty often;-).

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica allows you to do such math and you can write complete programs in it.

Otherwise, what you seek is a "library" to extend the built-in functionality of another programming language, such as Python or Java.

In the case of Python, the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) enables you to specify a precision in which math operations will be peformed.

Comment: I'll try Mathematica presently.

Comment: Are you working with whole numbers, or with numbers which also have a fractional part?  In either case, Mathematica will work, I am just curious as to what other solutions apply to you.

Comment: If you specify a precision, you can't do things like add 2 to a number with 500,000 zeros.. unless you use a bignum module or... Erlang.. which is free. Last I checked, Mathematica was expensive... and was WAY more powerful than just needing (nearly)infinite precision.

Comment: I thought there was a trial... but you must apply for it. I will probebly try Erlang or Python.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell (when using GHC) also has builtin support for arbitrarily long integers.  Here's a snippet showing the length of a number converted to a string.

```
Prelude> length $ show $ 10
2
Prelude> length $ show $ 1 + 2^2000000
602060
Prelude> let x = 2^200000
Prelude> let y = 2^200000 + 5
Prelude> y - x
5
```

Or you could just type `2^200000` at the interactive console and wait a couple minutes for it to print out all 600k+ characters.  I figured this way was a little simpler to demonstrate.

Comment: Depends on the version of Haskell. Helium, for example, does not support arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp has built-in support for arbitrary large numbers as well...

Answer (score 3):

Perl has a `bignum` module to do that sort of thing, and Python supports it natively.

Comment: Python doesn't have a bignum module: its integers are natively unlimited precision.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl, Python, Ruby, and Java can all do that. External libraries exist for everything else.

I rather like Ruby and Python because they automatically switch from `Fixnum` to `Bignum`. (Python: `int` to `long`.)

Comment: Erlang also does this, as do several other programming languages not on your list.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for isn't necessarily a language, but an arbitrary-precision library.

GMP would be a fast implementation in C/C++, and scripting languages that handles big integers would probably use something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In C or C++, you can use [GMP (Gnu Multi-Precision library)](http://gmplib.org/).

In Perl, you can use the [bignum module](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html).

Answer (score 1):

MIT/GNU Scheme has support for arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Many functional languages natively support arbitrary-precision numbers. Some have already been mentioned here, but I'll repeat them for completeness:

- Most versions of [Haskell](http://haskell.org).
- [Miranda](http://miranda.org.uk), a predecessor to Haskell.
- Some implementations of Scheme. In particular, [PLT Scheme](http://plt-scheme.org).
- [Erlang](http://erlang.org).

Answer (score 0):

I find Python quite good for this.